# Scala - how to map data from a file into different formats?

Tags: scala, collections, stream

I'm learning Scala basics and wrote a code to read data from a csv file and split it by commas. Now I'm trying to parse data so that I can get a map like this Map[Double, String]

So I decided to put it into `Map[Double, String]` since my file contains two fields (saleId (Double) and saleType (String)). But I'm getting an error (Expression of type Map[Nothing, Nothing] doesn't conform to expected type Map[Double, String]).

What is my mistake here? I thought that mapping with `line(0).toDouble, line(1).toString` will result in the expected Map[Double, String]

```
val stream : InputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/sales.csv")
  val lines: Iterator[String] = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(stream).getLines
  val map: Map[Double, String] = lines
    .map(_.split(",")
    .map(line => (line(0).toDouble, line(1).toString)))
    .toMap
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got your bracketing slightly wrong, it should be this:

```
val map: Map[Double, String] = lines
  .map(_.split(",")) // <- Added bracket
  .map(line => (line(0).toDouble, line(1).toString)) // <- Removed bracket
  .toMap
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you get your input in the format

```
val input = List("1.0,a","2.0,b","3.0,c","4.0,d")
```

then writing the function

```
input.map(x => (x.split(",")(0).toDouble,x.split(",")(1) )).toMap
```

will give you output in the form of

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[Double,String] = Map(1.0 -> a, 2.0 -> b, 3.0 -> c, 4.0 -> d)
```